# Pop up message box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code for a delete record in my table and I would like to add a pop up message "Are you sure you want to delete record" to give the user the option to cancel the delete record. Can someone help?

```
      <td class="recordCells"><div align="center"><a href="deleterecord.php?ID=<?php echo $row_rsInventory['ID']; ?>"><img src="../images/x.png" align="absmiddle" /></a></div></td>
```

Comment: you can just use an onclick event and in the js file connect the onclick event with `alert('Some message')`

Comment: A basic `alert` won't give the user the option to cancel. A `confirm` will.

Comment: do you want to create your own custom popup that's nice and pretty, or are you happy with just the browser alert box?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="recordCells"><div align="center"><a onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" href="deleterecord.php?ID=<?php echo $row_rsInventory['ID']; ?>"><img src="../images/x.png" align="absmiddle" /></a></div></td>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, When I press cancel on the confirm box it still deletes the record

Answer (score 0):

You could so do it on your form like so:

```
 <form name=FORMNAME action=ACTIONFILE method=POST onSubmit="alert('Note that deleting a record is permanent and irreversible.');">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sample code sir... hope it helps...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #pop
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        display: none;
    }
    #container
    {
        position: relative;
        width:500px;
        margin:100px auto;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pop" >
    <div id="container">
        <h1>CONFIRM</h1>
        <button id="yes">yes</button>
        <button id="no">no</button>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="stat"></p>
<button id="del">Delete file</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#del").on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#pop").show();
    })
    $("#yes,#no").click(function(){
        $("#pop").hide();
    })
    $("#yes").click(function(){
        $("#pop").hide();
        $("p#stat").html("DELETED")

        // PUT DELETE CODES HERE===============================
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```